# Character column split into list column in tibble

Tags: r, tibble

I have a tibble with character column of text and there is common starting and ending values to blocks, which I want to separate into lists column.

I want to separate each block that starts with "*****" and ends to 2 empty lines to list, so I can work them as separate.

```
text_tbl <- tibble(text = c("*****", "abc dfc", "abc dfc", "", "", "*****", "abc dfc", "abc dfc", "", ""))
```

So in the end, I would like to have list column in tibble that contains that block including "*****", empty lines are not necessary, but won't hurt either.

Result would look like this:

```
tibble(result = list(c("*****", "abc dfc", "abc dfc", "", ""), c("*****", "abc dfc", "abc dfc", "", "")))

  result   
  <list>   
1 <chr [5]>
2 <chr [5]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` to create groups and use `summarise` to combine text of every group as a list.

```
library(dplyr)

text_tbl %>%
  group_by(group = cumsum(text == '*****')) %>%
  summarise(text = list(text)) %>%
  select(-group)

#   text     
#  <list>   
#1 <chr [5]>
#2 <chr [5]>
```

Or using base R :

```
aggregate(text~group, transform(text_tbl, group = cumsum(text == '*****')), list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one tidyverse approach. For your example it is working. However, it doesn't account for the last two blank lines, but only looks for the separator at the start `*****`. Does this suffice?

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

text_tbl <- tibble(text = c("*****", "abc dfc", "abc dfc", "", "", "*****", "abc dfc", "abc dfc", "", ""))

text_tbl %>%
  mutate(group = ifelse(text == "*****", row_number(), NA)) %>% 
  fill(group) %>% 
  summarise(result = group_by(., group) %>% group_map(~.x)) 

#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   result          
#>   <list>          
#> 1 <tibble [5 × 1]>
#> 2 <tibble [5 × 1]>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I think this will work, I have to check with full sample. For general answer, is there away to use contains / starts_with in that if else? If I wanted to use some other phrase?

Comment: I think you can use mutate(group = ifelse(grepl("phrase", test), row_number(), NA))

Comment: Yes, you can basically use any regex function (base R, stringr, etc), to select strings. The tidyverse selection helpers only work on column names in a selection context.

Answer (score 1):

We could also use

```
library(data.table)
setDT(text_tbl)[, .(.(text)), .(group = cumsum(grepl('^\\*{5}$', text)))]
```